# Best way to protect resources hosted on Amazon S3?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

I’m creating a website where people can sign up and pay to watch videos. The site will be built in PHP and envisage it working as follows:

- Content creators upload their content (video file is uploaded to S3 bucket)
- Users can sign up, pay to watch uploaded videos

Therefore, I need a way to protect objects on a per-user basis so a user can’t pay to watch a video, inspect the HTML, and share the video’s URL with someone else who could then watch it without paying.

I thought about using IAM, creating an IAM user with access to purchased videos (objects) granted as a permission as a registered user on my website purchases videos, but watching [the introduction video from AWS](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ySl1gdH_7bY) it seems IAM users are more for granting access to people to be able to log into the AWS Console and manage my AWS services, and not as a method of granting privileges to objects to users of a web service.

If I’m right in thinking that IAM users are more for those accessing my services via the Console, what are my options for granting specific privileges to users of my application?

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2511329/how-do-you-let-only-authorized-user-have-access-contents-stored-in-amazons-s3 for ideas

Comment: You're correct that IAM users are not appropriate here.  You should probably validate users and hand out time-limited, signed S3 URLs.  That won't prevent the URL being shared within the time limit, of course, but if your users really want to share videos behind your back they can always share their credentials with others so you can't prevent it.  Time-limited URLs limit your exposure.

Comment: One way you could achieve what you want is to proxy the S3 object retrieval within your app so that all requests come through you and have to be within an authenticated session, but you'll quickly lose some of the key advantages of serving content directly from S3.

Comment: @jarmod Time-limited URLs sounds perfect. Do you know of any resources that cover implementing these in more depth?

Comment: @martin-bean Kyle's response below includes a link to the authoritative S3 page.  The AWS SDKs typically support signed URL generation (for example in java: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ShareObjectPreSignedURLJavaSDK.html) or you can generate REST URLs directly using the info at http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/2006-03-01/dev/RESTAuthentication.html). There are probably also a few GitHub projects using various languages that can help.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to use your own auth system in tandem with [Amazon's Signing and REST Authentication API](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/2006-03-01/dev/RESTAuthentication.html) and [AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/STS/latest/APIReference/API_AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity.html) to create temporary security credentials per user (upon request).